# how to insert a list value into a dataframe by row and column number?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, datatables

How do I insert a list value to a dataframe on a specific row and column?

For example say I have the dataframe

```
     source   col 1       col  2
0     a        xxx         xxx
1     b        xxx         xxx
2     c        xxx         xxx
3     a        xxx         xxx
```

My list is

```
list_value = [5,"text"]
```

How do I insert this list to the dataframe at row 1 and column 1 (col 1)

```
     source   col 1       col  2
0     a        xxx         xxx
1     b        5           xxx
2     c        text        xxx
3     a        xxx         xxx
```

**EDIT**

@Dev Arora

When I run your code I get this error.

```
d = {'col1': [1, 2,3,5,6,7], 'col2': [3, 4,5,"",5,6]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df

    col1 col2
  0 1     3
  1 2     4
  2 3     5
  3 5   
  4 6     5
  5 7     6

list_value = [5,"text"]

df.at[1, 'col2'] = list_value

df

    col1    col2
0   1       3
1   2       [5, 'text']
2   3       5
3   5   
4   6       5
5   7       6
```

Instead I want it to be

```
    col1    col2
0   1       3
1   2       5
2   3       'text'
3   5   
4   6       5
5   7       6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Assuming we're looking at pandas dataframes:*

I think the `df.at` operator is what you're looking for:

```
df = pd.read_csv("./test.csv")
list_value = [5,"text"]
 
string_to_input = ""
for val in list_value:
    string_to_input += str(val) + " "

df.at[<row_num>, "<col_name>"] = string_to_input
```

EDIT: If you're looking to add the values in just as a list you can also do

```
df = pd.read_csv("./test.csv")
list_value = [5,"text"]

df.at[<row_num>, "<col_name>"] = list_value
```

EDIT: Hmm okay lets take this from the top. As per the desired information in the post i.e. how to insert a value into a dataframe by row and column number, we're looking at `df.at`. What `df.at` does is insert a value in a dataframe based on the specific row number and column number given. Insofar in the example:

```
d = {'col1': [1, 2,3,5,6,7], 'col2': [3, 4,5,"",5,6]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df

    col1 col2
  0 1     3
  1 2     4
  2 3     5
  3 5   
  4 6     5
  5 7     6

list_value = [5,"text"]

df.at[1, 'col2'] = list_value

df

    col1    col2
0   1       3
1   2       [5, 'text']
2   3       5
3   5   
4   6       5
5   7       6
```

That is exactly what has happened. This is not an error.
The command `df.at[1, 'col2'] = list_value` specifies that at *row 1* and *col2*  insert the `list_value` which is `[5, 'text']`.

If you want a dataframe that looks like this by specifically indicating the desired row and column for each insertion:

```
    col1    col2
0   1       3
1   2       5
2   3       'text'
3   5   
4   6       5
5   7       6
```

Something like this is required:

```
df.at[1, "col2"] = 5
df.at[2, "col2"] = 'text'
```

The above code specifies that at row 1, col2 insert 5, and at row 2 col2 insert 'text'. Hope this helps!

Comment: the issue seems to be it just puts the value in the one cell?

Comment: Isn't that the desired behavior? Oh wait did you want to input the contents of the list as a list? I've added that above.

Comment: sorry but I get this error "ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable"

Comment: Interesting the code above is working fine for me, could you add a minimum reproducible sample to your question so we can see what's going on?

Comment: thanks will do it tmr way from desk (work) it looks like when i do it with basic df it works but not with my larger data work.

Comment: Sounds good, btw if I've answered your question, would you mind creating a separate post for any new errors you have and marking this answer accepted?

Comment: I update the edit to show the error I was coming across.

Comment: Just took a look at it and added a clarification above. Hope this helps! If I have answered your question, please accept this answer.